# Дисциплина кода: это старая школа или неправильная?

Tags: code-style

Прямо сейчас заканчиваю проект, который просто необходимо было посадить на Битрикс. Добрая половина времени у меня ушла на выход из затруднительных ситуаций, вызванных структурой системы, структурой путей (/bitrix/components/bitrix/sale.personal.order/templates/.default/bitrix/bitrix/sale.personal.order.list), стилем кода и стилем именования. За все время разработки я выдумал достаточно много матерных конструкций в адрес разработчиков системы. И вот теперь я задал себе вопрос, которым они, видимо, не были озадачены: если кто-то будет разбирать мой код, будет ли желать моей смерти?

Скажем, редактор jsfiddle меня просто убивает этим своим отступом:

```
$('.someclass').stop(true, true).addClass('open').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    box-shadow: '#000 0px 0px 200px 50px'
}, 'slow', function()
                                          {
                                          $(this).addClass('ready');
                                          });
```

Такой отступ можно читать, но тоже неудобно:

```
function dome_func(some_var)
{
    var res = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < some_var; i++)
    {
        res += i;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Такой стиль все видали. Вопрос: многие ли из вас так пишет? Может ли кто-то объяснить удобство?

Когда я начинал на похапе писать фреймворк (ну а кто не пробовал?), я старался придерживаться стиля jQuery, который поразил меня когда-то: один и тот же метод одновременно является и getter-ом, и setter-ом, при чем для последнего можно передавать как одно значение, так и массив — посмотрите хотя бы на `jQuery.css(...)`.

Нельзя также пропустить и «chaining» — тоже добавляет удобства.

Именование. `ГорбатыеИмена` или `такие_вот`? К примеру, константы у меня обязательно в верхнем регистре. Как тут быть? Конечно же, слова нужно отделять: `BASE_PATH`. Но как быть с именами ф-ций и переменных? Когда речь идет о группе методов, направленных на операции с одной и то же сущностью, я ставлю префикс, например:

```
$lib = new lib_instance();  // library instance

$lib->tags_get_list();  // синоним $lib->tags_get_available();
$lib->tags_get($id);
$lib->tags_add($tag, $rewrite_id = NULL);
```

Но в последнее время я стал замечать, что кол-во слов достигает и 4 (с префиксом), поэтому читаемость тоже падает. Что, CamelCase? Тогда как быть с префиксами:

```
$lib->tags_getList();   // синоним $lib->tags_getAvailable();
```

или так:

```
$lib->tagsGetList();    // синоним $lib->tagsGetAvailable();
```

или так:

```
$lib->TagsGetList();    // синоним $lib->TagsGetAvailable();
```

Про пути и структуру систем я говорить не стану, ибо в этой теме ничто, окромя своего мозга не спасет. А вот что касается стиля писанины — тут решит большинство.

Вступление в силу малой важности я вынес в конец топика.

Начинал я кодить по книге (печать ~95—2000 г.), выданной мне в 3-м классе, где в разделе «Информатика» рассматривались алгоритмы и различные задачки. Условие и решение приводилось на одном из 3 языков: Basic, Pascal и Кумир. И, хотя черпать оттуда было почти нечего, но основы стиля я взял еще оттуда:

```
function some_proc(some_var: byte): integer;
var 2nd_var: string;
    i: integer;
begin
for i := 0 to some_var - 1 do
    begin
    if i mod 2 = 0 then
        result := result + i;
        else
        result := result + i div 2;
    end;
end;
```

*Не смотрите на смысл, это рыба*

То есть, `begin`/`end` обязательно находятся на одном уровне (tab), но `begin`/`end`, обозначающие границы тела ф-ции — без отступов. Каждая новая секция (тело условия, цикл, etc.) обязательно отбивается слева еще одним tab-ом. Операторы отбиваются пробелами слева и справа (есть исключения). В секции объявления переменных каждая переменная выведена на новую строку; все они — на одном уровне (здесь `var` занимает меньше места, чем tab, при том не имеет закрывающего слова, поэтому первая переменная идет на той же строке, что и само слово `var`).

Именно те 30 страниц гниги определили мой стиль писанины. И, хотя мне переучиваться поздновато, чувствую, что сам уже запутался. Посему принять новый стиль будет совсем немногим сложнее, чем разобраться в своем.

Не для холивара, обсуждение будет действительно полезно.

Всем дисциплину, посоны!

Comment: Не знаю, чья цитата:

> Пишите код так, как будто сопровождать его будет склонный к насилию психопат, который знает, где вы живёте.

Comment: А что неудобного вы видите в форматировании `dome_func`?

Comment: :)

Вопрос в том, к чему привыкло большинство людей, среди которых вполне могут оказаться и психопаты (коим стал я сам за последние 3 месяца).

Comment: > А что неудобного вы видите в форматировании dome_func?

Для меня это удобно до тех пор, пока это не что-то вроде `some_booklib_get_page_by_id`. Ну а кроме того, это удобно мне, но не большинству, видимо: почти каждый код, который я вижу в последнее время, написан CamelCas-ом. Особенно на java(script)-е.

Comment: Хм. В каждом языке есть свои стандарты. В некоторых даже есть много, в каждой группе разработчиков свой: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style (и каждая группа считает свой стиль единственно верным и удобным).

Comment: @Bars, этих стилей (более-менее нравящихся большинству программистов) существует (с разными вариациями), наверное, с десяток.

Договориться об едином стиле не получиться никогда.

В идеале желательно, чтобы код каждого большого проекта был написан всеми участниками в одном стиле.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за ссылку, теперь знаю наименование стиля отступов, к которому привык сам — Whitesmiths style :) В статье сказано, что он очень непопулярен.

@avp, в том и дело, что этих стилей у каждого — один единственный из этого десятка, так вот интересует меня именно распределение. Я не намереваюсь учинить переворот и двигать всех «верным путем», а наоборот — прильнуть к большинству.

> В идеале желательно, чтобы код каждого большого проекта был написан всеми участниками в одном стиле.

Да, вот ребятки при написании Битрикса справились: написали все в одинаковом Xerovom style.

Comment: Прочитал. Все хорошо, но что спросить-то хотели?

Comment: @Bars, как вариант, могу посоветовать не придумывать велосипед хотя бы касательно стиля - посмотрите стандарты у разных фреймворков и выберите тот, который понравится лично вам больше. Может вашим велосипедом никто и пользоваться не будет, а вы тут расстараетесь для большинства :) Мне вот понравился стандарт фреймворка Kohana.  
Или возьмите от всех что-то и оформите свой стандарт.  
Что касается длинных названий, то у того же Zend'а написано "многословность приветствуется". Так что, дело полностью ваше.

Comment: @Bars, а нужно ли делать, как большинство? Главное, чтобы самому нравилось.

Я вот (как выяснилось из ссылки @VladD), пишу определение функций в стиле GNU, а тело в K&R, но с маленькими отступами).